# How to obfuscate a html hyperlink

Tags: html, hyperlink, obfuscation

I have an image hosting project. I would like to encode/obfuscate the html links as in http://htmlobfuscator.com/

Does anyone have any idea how can i get this done?

Comment: I think that depends how you would like to protect your data, the code or the image. There's nothing to really stop people from getting your image as long as they are displayed in their browser.

Comment: htmlobfuscator will scramble your code, however it eventually outputs a normal readable DOM, and hovering on a link will reveal its address. What would that achieve? What is your purpose?